# change font in caption text

Tags: fonts, captions

I want to change the font in the caption, so I tried this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\myfont[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=Lining]{Ubuntu Condensed}
\usepackage[font=\myfont, labelfont=bf]{caption} 

\begin{document}

    This is text font

    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \caption{ ... and this should be the figure font}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It doesn't seem to work, it is clear that `font=\myfont` is wrong, but I don't know how to change it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your font beforehand.

[image: figure font]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\myfont[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=Lining]{Ubuntu Condensed}
\usepackage{caption} 
\DeclareCaptionFont{quack}{\myfont}
\captionsetup{font=quack, labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

    This is text font

    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \caption{ ... and this should be the figure font}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest strategy is to declare Ubuntu Condensed as the sans serif font. You wouldn't use two different sans serif fonts in the same document, would you? `;-)`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Ubuntu Condensed}

\captionsetup{font=sf}

\begin{document}

This is text font

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{ ... and this should be the figure font}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `Mapping=tex-text` option is deprecated and should be `Ligatures=TeX`, but need not be specified as it is loaded by default.

Also, Ubuntu Condensed has no boldface variant, so `labelfont=bf` is useless. The font also has a single choice for numbers (lining).

[image]

The same output with `\newfontfamily`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\ubuntufont}{Ubuntu Condensed}

\DeclareCaptionFont{ubuntu}{\ubuntufont}
\captionsetup{font=ubuntu}

\begin{document}

This is text font

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{ ... and this should be the figure font}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```